# C: edit file to remove null characters:

Tags: c, fopen, fclose, fgetc

I thought this would be an easy task, after a couple of tries I try the tried and true write to a temp than reopen and rewrite:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     FILE *f = fopen("main2.c","r");
     FILE *t = fopen("temp","w");
     int c;
     int count = 0;
     while((c = fgetc(f))!=EOF)
     {
          if(c)
          {
               fputc(c,t);
          }
          else
          {
               printf("null found\n");
          }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(t);
    FILE *n = fopen("main2.c","w");
    FILE *w = fopen("temp","r");
    while((c=fgetc(w))!=EOF)
    {
          fputc(c,n);
    }
    fclose(n);
    fclose(w);
    return 0;
}
```

this just spits out a bunch of chinese characters. Could the underlying character encoding be the issue? Or am I just a total noob here?

My hex editor won't let me copy/paste. I don't know how I can get the file up here in its original condition so I have it zipped in google docs let me know immediately if you cant get it:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4UPOuCR5uRGZzJQZUpVaktKYlk

EDIT: wait wait here it is via HxE Edit:

```
FF FE 23 00 69 00 6E 00 63 00 6C 00 75 00 64 00 65 00 20 00 3C 00 73 00 74 00 64 00   
6C  00 69 00 62 00 2E 00 68 00 3E 00 0D 00 0A 00 23 00 69 00 6E 00 63 00 6C 00 75 00 64 00 
65 00 20 00 3C 00 61 00 6C 00 6C 00 65 00 67 00 72 00 6F 00 2E 00 68 00 3E 00 0D 00 0A 00 
23 00 69 00 6E 00 63 00 6C 00 75 00 64 00 65 00 20 00 22 00 6D 00 6F 00
```

Comment: It would be nice to see a hex-dump of the original file (or part of it.) Additionally, why are you re-reading and writing the file? Just delete the original and rename the temp file to the original's filename.

Comment: I thought that even C coders had caught on to the practice of variable names > 1 character. Since you don't unlink temp, have you checked whether it is good? If so then your "copy" fails else it's your null removal.

Comment: The output is a sequence of bytes (because that's what a file is in C). By which process do those bytes become (interpreted as) "a bunch of chinese characters" for you?

Comment: "Could the underlying character encoding be the issue?" <-- Yes, sure. Or the file could contain Chinese characters after all. What's the actual encoding of the file and what's the expected?

Comment: What is the encoding of your input? (`main2.c`) The `fgetc()` returns an `int` from an `unsigned char`, which is one byte in size. Therefore, if your input data are multibyte, then who knows what you will get out if you read in and strip individual bytes from the stream? Look at the `fgetwc()` function, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are that you are removing NULL bytes because the input is UTF-16 Unicode.  If so, you also must remove the byte-order mark (BOM) at the start of the file.  If the first two bytes are 0xFF, 0xFE then you have a little-endian UTF-16 file.  Discard them!  If you leave them in, every pair of ASCII characters in your source will be treated as a combined 16-bit character code.  Strangeness will ensue.

Likewise if the first two bytes are 0xFE, 0xFF, the file is big-endian UTF-16 and you must also delete those two bytes, else the file will be treated as 16-bit codes again, only with high bytes first.

Comment: so remove the nulls plus FF and FE at the beginning and it will read like UTF-8?

Comment: Not really. If there are codepoints in the range 0x80..0xFF present in the original file, they won't be properly encoded.  Nor will they match any code page I know of.  This quick-n-dirty conversion really only works if all original codes were ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

Open the files in binary mode:

```
 FILE *f = fopen("main2.c","rb");
 FILE *t = fopen("temp","wb");
```

Comment: This *may* be the issue, or it may not. But certainly recommended if you are working with files byte-by-byte.